# Acess token is not coming

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have linked Alexa with Google OAuth2.
For the first time I click on account linking I receive accessToken but after some time(1 0r 2 hrs) I am unable to receive.(I get only user id) 
Does Amazon has provided some mechanism to generate fresh access token as it expires in 1 hr so that access token is not expired.

Comment: Which of the two account linking methods do you use?

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying?I have done configuration with respected parameters on Alexa account linking section

Comment: `Implicit Grant` or `Auth Code Grant`

Comment: Normally if you create a token u can give it an expire date. Try to change the expire date on server side.

By useing the authorization Grant Type ´Auth Code Grant´ you are able set a token refresh URL.

Comment: @Genfood Auth Code Grant